# What is the easiest way to install Ruby on my server

Tags: ruby

I want to code pages in Ruby so that my website can be run in Ruby (just like I have a php install on my server).
What's the easiest way to go about this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Heroku](http://www.heroku.com/) and forget about Ruby server installation.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question varies heavily depending on your operating system.  But instructions for downloading and installing ruby on many systems are on [the download page](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/).

However, if you're planning on using it for a webserver, you probably also want [Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/download).